# tf idf similarity

Tags: java, text, similarity, tf-idf

I am using TF/IDF to calculate similarity. For example if I have the following two doc.

```
Doc A => cat dog
Doc B => dog sparrow
```

It is normal it's similarity would be 50% but when I calculate its TF/IDF. It is as follow

Tf values for Doc A

```
dog tf = 0.5
cat tf = 0.5
```

Tf values for Doc B

```
dog tf = 0.5
sparrow tf = 0.5
```

IDF values for Doc A

```
dog idf = -0.4055
cat idf = 0
```

IDF values for Doc B

```
dog idf = -0.4055 ( without +1 formula 0.6931)
sparrow idf = 0
```

TF/IDF value for Doc A

```
0.5x-0.4055 + 0.5x0 = -0.20275
```

TF/IDF values for Doc B

```
0.5x-0.4055 + 0.5x0 = -0.20275
```

Now it looks like there is -0.20275 similarity. Is it? 
Or am I missing something ? 
Or is any kind of next step too? Please tell me so I can calculate that too.

I used tf/idf formula which Wikipedia mentioned

Comment: Are you using Apache Mahout to calculate it? If yes can you please let me know the steps that need to be taken. I have to develop a Prototype to Calculate TF IDF using Apache Mahout. junaid_surqyahoo.co.in

Answer (score 17):

Let's see if I get your question:
You want to calculate the TF/IDF similarity between the two documents:

```
Doc A: cat dog
```

and

```
Doc B: dog sparrow
```

I take it that this is your whole corpus. Therefore `|D| = 2`
Tfs are indeed 0.5 for all words.
To calculate the IDF of 'dog', take `log(|D|/|d:dog in d| = log(2/2) = 0`
Similarly, the IDFs of 'cat' and 'sparrow' are `log(2/1) = log(2) =1`
(I use 2 as the log base to make this easier).

Therefore, the TF/IDF values for 'dog' will be 0.5*0 = 0
the TF/IDF value for 'cat' and 'sparrow' will be 0.5*1 = 0.5

To measure the similarity between the two documents, you should calculate the cosine 
between the vectors in the (cat, sparrow, dog) space:
(0.5, 0 , 0) and (0, 0.5, 0) and get the result 0.

To sum it up:

1. You have an error in the IDF calculations.
2. This error creates wrong TF/IDF values.
3. The Wikipedia article does not explain the use of TF/IDF for similarity well enough. I like [Manning, Raghavan & Schütze's explanation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/tf-idf-weighting-1.html) much better.

Comment: Thanks Yuval ! ! ! 
You made my life easy :)
There are two problems 1 that i was using natural log. I couldn't find any log2 function in java but i will figure it out.
The 2nd problem is more important. I couldn't understand how are you meassuring similarity with cosine? When tf/idf said 50% similarity then why cosine is saying 0% ???

Comment: You're welcome. I believe using natural log is better, it was just easier to explain using base 2. Let's clarify the cosine similarity:
TF/IDF is purely a representation: You convert a vector of word counts to a vector of TF/IDF values. The cosine similarity is the scalar multiplication between two normalized vectors; The vectors can be the original counts or transformed by TF/IDF. In the case as you stated it, the scalar multiplication will be zero because we either have words appearing in only one vector, or a common word with a zero score ('dog'). HTH.

Comment: Thanks Yuval, If I use natural log then my Tf/Idf values are different then yours. If i use log2 then i think i get correct results. Can you please tell me what is the difference between LSI and vector space? Sorry it sounds dumb question. If you can send me a good tutorial how to implement LSI. it would be great help

Comment: This is by no means a dumb question. Informally, LSI is a way to weight term frequency vectors that uses more information from the term-document matrix than TF/IDF does, via a singular value decomposition (SVD). I suggest you read this: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/09/ir-math-with-java-tf-idf-and-lsi.html 
for a theoretical explanation and an implementation guide.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Manning, Raghavan & Schütze's book - it is a great resource!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to take ln instead of log.

Answer (score 0):

```
def calctfidfvec(tfvec, withidf):
    tfidfvec = {}
    veclen = 0.0

    for token in tfvec:
        if withidf:
            tfidf = (1+log10(tfvec[token])) * getidf(token)
        else:
            tfidf = (1+log10(tfvec[token]))
        tfidfvec[token] = tfidf 
        veclen += pow(tfidf,2)

    if veclen > 0:
        for token in tfvec: 
            tfidfvec[token] /= sqrt(veclen)

    return tfidfvec

def cosinesim(vec1, vec2):
    commonterms = set(vec1).intersection(vec2)
    sim = 0.0
    for token in commonterms:
        sim += vec1[token]*vec2[token]

    return sim
```